# How to manage the execution order with Asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, upload, blueimp

Let me explain my problem. I have a form with some *input[type=text]* and 2 *input[type=file]* & there is just one validation button.

When there is a click on the button, I want to submit the data and to upload the files (if the input[type=file] are not empty).

Another point: The control for the type of accepted file and of the accepted size should be done when the file is selected.
It means  that if the file selected does not match with the constraints, an error message is displayed and the input[type=file] stay empty.

For uploading I use "**blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload**". 
You will find below the code for an instance of this plugin (It's for an image uploading)

```
$('#file-img').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    autoUpload: false,
    formData: {type: 'businessPicture'},
    add: function (e, data) {
        var uploadErrors = [];
        var acceptFileTypes = /^image\/(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i;
        if(data.originalFiles[0]['type'].length && !acceptFileTypes.test(data.originalFiles[0]['type'])) {
            uploadErrors.push('Not an accepted file type');
        }
        if(data.originalFiles[0]['size'].length && data.originalFiles[0]['size'] > 4000000) {
            uploadErrors.push('File size is too big');
        }
        if(uploadErrors.length > 0) {
            alert(uploadErrors.join("\n"));
        } else {
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                $("#txt-file-img").val(file.name);
            });
            $("#btn_add_valid").on('click',function () { 
        $("#loading_img_modal").modal("show");  
                data.submit();
        });
        }
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        $("#output").html('<p class="valid">SUCCESS!</p>');
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $("#preview-picture").css("max-width","160px");
            $("#preview-picture").css("max-height","150px");
            $("#preview-picture").attr("src",file.url+'#'+ new Date().getTime()); 
        });
    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#upload-progress .bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        ).text(
            progress + '%'
        );
    },
    fail: function (e, data) {
        $("#output").html('<p class="error">FAIL!</p>');
    }
});
```

You can see that I bind the submit of the file to the click on the #btn_add_valid

```
$("#btn_add_valid").on('click',function () { 
    $("#loading_img_modal").modal("show");  
    data.submit();
 });
```

I have another similar instance for the upload of document (.pdf, .doc....).
There is also another AJAX function called when the buton #btn_add_valid is clicked. This last function modify the database with the information mentioned by the user in the input[type=text].

My problem come from the fact that these 3 functions are bound with the same event $("#btn_add_valid").on('click',... and I can't manage the order for their execution.

So you are wondering why it's a problem?

1. **Because the path for the uploaded files is defined after the database modification**. I use the last id of the table as a name for creating a folder with the uploaded files.
   So the first executed function must be the function with the databse modification.
2. Because I display a modal with a progress bar for each upload. Whatever will be the order of the upload I need to wait the end of the first upload to hide the first progress bar and display the second one (if there are 2 files uploaded)

Do you have a solution for this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be downvoted. You should research promises like the `q` library.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sometimes I don't understand what I did wrong and why people give a bad mark. I will take a look at the q library.

Comment: For example you want this order: `first -> second -> third`. First approach, call `second` at the end of `first` function and call `third` function at the end of `second` function. Second approach is using promise chaining, See more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise.